# C++ class in Cocoa

Tags: c++, objective-c, compilation

Any ideas why Xcode wont let me define a c++ class in my cocoa project?

I am trying to use a C++ class in my cocoa project but I am getting build errors just creating the c++ header file.

```
class SomeClass{
public:
     int count;
};
```

Expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before 'SomeClass' in .....

If I remove all code from the header file, ?the cpp file builds without any errors and is included in the list of compiled sources...

Comment: What suffix does the header file have ? And are you trying to #include the C++ header file in an Objective C source file ?

Comment: Sorry, the header has a .h and the implementation file has .mm
I also have the semicolon but forgot to put it in the sample code...

Answer (score 5):

Ensure that your Objective-C source files have the `.mm` extension so that they are treated as Objective-C++ files (there are other ways of getting Xcode to treat your files as Objective-C++ source even if they don't have the `.mm` extension, but it is easier just to use the `.mm` extension), and also follow PeterK's advice about appending a semicolon after the class declaration.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to add a semicolon:

```
class SomeClass{
public:
     int count;
};
```